# NetLogo referencing user-defined variables AND linking a turtle and patch without being in proximity

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to figure out a way for a car to reserve a parking space (patch) in my world. I have created a reserved boolean for patches, but do not know how to link this reservation with a specific turtle. I thought of linking the turtle and the patch (I am new to this program) but realized that links are turtle-turtle only.

In addition to that, I am trying to construct a loop to search for spots closest to my destination (xcor 0). Where the turtle will reserve the closest spot to the destination (and the turtle himself as a tiebreaker as xcor -1 and xcor 1 are the same distance from the destination).

I am referencing my patch-owned reserved boolean incorrectly, but more importantly, can I link this reservation or some other type of variable to a turtle?

```
patches-own [empty reserved]
to reserve
  ifelse ((patch 0 -1 != nobody) and (patch 0 -1 [reserved] = false))
  [ask patch 0 -1 [set reserved true
      set pcolor red]]
  let i 1
  [do while reserved = true[
      ifelse (patch -i -1 != nobody and (patch -i -1 [reserved] = false))
      [ask patch -i 1 [ set reserved true
          set pcolor red]
      [ if patch i -1 != nobody and (patch i -1 [reserved] = false)
        [ask patch i -1 [ set reserved true
            set pcolor red]]]]
      set i i + 1]
  ]
 end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a few minor points:

- The proper way to refer to the `reserved` variable of `patch 0 -1` is `[ reserved ] of patch 0 -1`.
- You can't have a link between a patch and a turtle, but you can store a reference to a turtle in a patch variable. You could have a `reserved-by` reference instead of a `reserved` boolean. You would assign it by doing: `ask patch 0 -1 [ set reserved-by turtle 0 ]` or something equivalent.
- I see you have an `empty` patch variable. You're not doing anything with it in your code, but I suspect that any use you might have had in mind would be better served by `not any? turtles-here`.

And the main problem:

It is very rare that loops are the best approach in NetLogo. In general, you should try thinking in terms of agentsets with which you can use the many built-in functions that you will find in [the NetLogo dictionnary](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html). In your specific case, it could be something like:

```
patches-own [ reserved-by ]

to reserve-closest-free-spot [ destination ]
  let free-spots patches with [ pycor = -1 and not is-turtle? reserved-by ]
  let closest-to-destination free-spots with-min [ distance destination ]
  let closest-to-me min-one-of closest-to-destination [ distance myself ]
  ask closest-to-me [
    set reserved-by myself
    set pcolor red
  ]
end
```

And then you can use the `reserve-closest-free-spot` procedure like this, for example:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ask n-of 10 patches [ sprout 1 [ reserve-closest-free-spot patch 0 -1 ]]
  ; Show the reservations:
  ask patches with [ is-turtle? reserved-by ] [ show reserved-by ]
end
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for all of the help I truly appreciate it. This looks perfect!